# Crontab not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell, cron

```
#/bin/bash
cd /home/oracle/scripts/mon_scripts/
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=test
cat /dev/null > /home/oracle/scripts/mon_scripts/wget_cache.out
a=`sqlplus test/test123@/home/oracle/scripts/mon_scripts/flushtable.sql|grep -A 2 COUNT|tail -n1`
if [ $a == 0 ];then
(
echo "Empty- Nothing Processed"
)
else
(
echo "localhost" >> wget_cache.out
ssh localhost wget http://localhost/cs/ContentServer?pagename=debug/ReloadRefData -O - >> wget_cache.out
echo "--------------" >> wget_cache.out
echo "localhost" >> wget_cache.out
wget http://localhost:7005/cs/ContentServer?pagename=debug/ReloadRefData -O - >> wget_cache.out
echo "--------------"
echo "localhost" >> wget_cache.out
wget http://localhost:7005/cs/ContentServer?pagename=debug/ReloadRefData -O - >> wget_cache.out
sqlplus test/test123 @/home/oracle/scripts/mon_scripts/deletetable.sql
)
fi
```

The above script is working fine within the command prompt but its not working using crontab - please suggest , IN crontab, it seems if condition is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crontab doesn't execute jobs with the same environment variables than your user.

So it doesn't know where to look for binaries (`PATH` is not defined of different).  You have to use only absolute paths and not relative paths to execute commands.

For example, replace `wget` by `/usr/bin/wget`.

Comment: Its not checking the condition correctly - its directly going to the else condition

Comment: "The above script is working fine within the command prompt", so I guess it's not the main problem

Comment: That is what im trying to figure out - Its working fine if we execute it like                    "sh test.sh" ,  but not working from crontab

Comment: Did you try my solution? Replace all relative paths by absolute paths. I'm sure sqlplus is not found and that's the reason why the condition doesn't work as expected.